# While crawling, the file download path is JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, web-crawler

I am practicing crawling to download files.

I am crawling a site.

```
http://www.hanaif.re.kr/kor/jsp/board/board.jsp?sa=ci&bid=90&pg=1&no=32919
```

I looked at the html code of this bulletin board.

I found this.

```
<a href="JavaScript:downloadClick( '부채보유_가구의_재무상황_점검_및_시사점(2016가금복).pdf', '20170201141002555_5623' )" title="부채보유_가구의_재무상황_점검_및_시사점(2016가금복).pdf">부채보유_가구의_재무상황_점검_및_시사점...</a>
```

As a result of trying to find download url, I found this type of address.

```
http://www.hanaif.re.kr/kor/jsp/board/include/download.jsp?realFileName=' + (realFileName) + '&fileName=' + (fileName)
```

After coding, My program output this result.

```
http://www.hanaif.re.kr/kor/jsp/board/include/download.jsp?realFileName=20170201141002555_5623&fileName=부채보유_가구의_재무상황_점검_및_시사점(2016가금복).pdf
```

The file was downloaded well.

But,

```
http://www.hanaif.re.kr/kor/jsp/board/board.jsp?sa=ci&bid=42&pg=32&no=17050
```

This is another post on the same bulletin board.

The html code of this is as follows.

```
<a href="JavaScript:downloadClick( 'IMF 10년의 회고와 시사점.pdf', 'IMF 10년의 회고와 시사점.pdf' )" title="IMF 10년의 회고와 시사점.pdf">IMF 10년의 회고와 시사점.pdf</a>
```

Again, my program output the following results.

```
http://www.hanaif.re.kr/kor/jsp/board/include/download.jsp?realFileName=IMF 10년의 회고와 시사점.pdf&fileName=IMF 10년의 회고와 시사점.pdf
```

However, I can not download that file.

More precisely, it is possible to download files via the url.

However, the document can not be loaded.

What is the problem?

Also, is there a way to easily get a file download url from a JavaScript implemented site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you click the download link, it post data to server:
[image]

```
import requests

payload = {'fileName': 'IMF 10년의 회고와 시사점.pdf',
         'path': '/kor/jsp/board/include/download.jsp',
         'realFileName': 'IMF 10년의 회고와 시사점.pdf'}

r = requests.post('http://www.hanaif.re.kr/kor/jsp/board/include/download.jsp', data=payload, stream=True )
filename = payload['fileName']
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        f.write(chunk)
```

Comment: @ The URL is the post URL.
I want to know download url

Comment: @ I know the post format. Is it possible to download a file without sending a payload even though it is a post? 
Why did the previous post download properly?

Comment: @you should check the concept of HTTP and figure out how it works.